# Send data using a already open socket in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I built a small program that listen to arbitrary connections and processes their requests, saving the events and connections information to a sqlite database. Once the connection is closed and opened again, it updates the source port.

This is working like a charm, but now I want to be able to randomly send those hosts messages, and I can't open new connections to them because they may be behind a NAT.

Is there a way to utilize the already open connections to transmit data? I mean, I could write a function in the `thread_cliente`'s while True, that checks if there is a message in the database to be delivered to it, but I figured that there must be an easier or a more elegant way to do it.

Below is my code for a socket server. I translated my comments from Portuguese to English. Unfortunately my co-workers insist on using Portuguese variables, so this may cause some confusion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import sys
import logging
from _thread import start_new_thread
from MyPack import all_my_stuff


def print_help():
    print(f'{sys.argv[0]} [TCP Port] [Someting that my program do]')
    sys.exit()


def start_server(porta):
    servico = socket.socket()

    try:
        servico.bind(('', porta))
    except socket.error as e:
        logging.error(e)

    servico.listen(1024) # Is 1024 the max simultaneous client number?

    while True:
        cliente, endereco = servico.accept()
        logging.debug(
            f'New connection {endereco[0]}:{endereco[1]}'
        )
        try:
            start_new_thread(thread_cliente, (cliente, endereco, ))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)

    servico.close()


def thread_cliente(conexao, endereco):
    while True:
        data = conexao.recv(128)
        if data:
            resposta = None
            sibulla_db.insere_conexao(endereco[0], endereco[1], sys.argv[1])
            resposta = all_my_stuff.do_something(data, sys.argv[1], endereco)
            if resposta:
                logging.debug(f'Sending data: {resposta}')
                conexao.sendall(bytes.fromhex(resposta))
        else:
            #   Close connection
            logging.debug(
                f'Connection closed {endereco[0]}:{endereco[1]}'
            )
            break
    conexao.close()


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1 or sys.argv[1] == 'help':
        #   are you running it right, or asking for help
        print_help()

    #   Log
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
        filename='sibulla.log',
        level=logging.DEBUG
    )

    #   Start it
    start_server(int(sys.argv[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @gst. Much more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending back on the original socket is probably the best way to talk to the clients.

If you're not concerned about the number of clients getting too high, you could keep the client connection open until you need it, and save the socket somewhere for later use.

Comment: What do you mean with save the socket for later use? I mean, this is what i am thinking in doing.

Comment: Just stash it as an attribute of whatever class you're using to hold client state.  And if you don't have a class for that yet, now might be a good time to add one :)